# Visual Studio 2015 StandardCollector.Service.exe runaway I/O

Tags: visual-studio-2015, io, visual-studio-debugging

Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3) is coming to a complete halt due to massive I/O caused by the StandardCollector.Service.exe. Debugging a project results in a sustained 200 mb / sec data written in the temp directory. All performance data (etl).

Memory allocation is normal.

This behaviour is new. I used Visual Studio 15 for years without (but for the usual) complaints.

I tracked it down to the Diagnostic Tools. Disabling Diagnostic Tools in Tool -> Debugging -> General -> Options -> Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging solves the I/O problem. However this is not a permanent solution since I rely on this feature.

Q: What causes the massive I/O when Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging is switched on?

Comment: @ orion6.andre.jager, Under Tools->Options->IntelliTrace, uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace", and then use the diagnostic tools, how about the result?

Comment: That behavior is not new, it has always done that.  The workaround you found is the correct one.  Only ever turn it back on when you really, really need it and that better be on a modest unit-test style program.  It is a wiz-bang feature that was useful to get programmers to upgrade to VS2015 and to give newbies insight in how their programs impact the system.   But it runs out of gas at just about the exact time they *really* need it, when they learned enough to write high-perf programs.  It simply does not scale, and can't.  Congratulations btw.

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT. Before turning of the "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging", I turned of "Enable IntelliTrace". This, however, did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT, thanks for the links. In contrast to the issues described in the links, I do not have any memory leaks. In my case the process is writing data at > 200 mb / sec to disc and won't stop bringing Visual Studio to a halt and not recovering.

Comment: @orion6.andre.jager, Sorry for my misunderstanding, I will report and discuss this issue with other members, if I get any latest information, I will share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work on Visual Studio, specifically the Diagnostic Tools

You have the CPU Usage tool enabled which is a profiler that uses event tracing for windows (ETW). Basically it is collecting a CPU stack every millisecond and that information is getting written to an ETL file that we analyze and display performance information from. We persist whether or not you turned it on between debug sessions, specifically so that you can turn it on, restart debugging, and profile app startup. One of our biggest issues is that it is easy to turn on and forget.

To turn it off, switch to the CPU Usage tab in the Diagnostic Tools and press the "Enable CPU Collection" button (text is different based on VS version). The CPU graph above should switch from green to blue indicating that it has been turned off. Also, in the latest version of Visual Studio we have added resource limits which will disable the diagnostic tools if the disk or memory usage on the system gets too low, which was common when the CPU tool was enabled and forgotten about.

Comment: A huge 21 GB `System.1.etl` file got dropped on my system and I kept getting disk space warnings until I realized what was up. I'm not sure the default resource limits for disk space actually makes sense. Basing it on total disk space rather than free space might not be the best idea.

Comment: I can also confirm that the disk limit functionality definitely does not work on latest version of Visual Studio (15.5.2).

Comment: Unfortunately, using free disk space is a bit more complicated as it is a moving target and could incur a slight performance hit, but I'll take a look.

If the disk limit functionality is not working please file a bug via the feedback in VS. Note, we have a minimum session duration of 5 minutes in which we will continue to run even if we have exceed the disk or memory limits. This is to help people will small drives who are trying to collect traces but are hitting the limits.